Python venv: Dependence on default OS version
I would like to have multiple virtual environments, some with a different python version itself. I am uncertain about the base version of the python I should use. For instace, if I create venv dependent virtual environments using python provided by my current Ubuntu OS, say 3.8, and later I upgrade Ubuntu itself and that updates python to version 3.10, will the virtual environments created under previous Ubuntu still work?

Virtualenvs do depend on their base interpreter being intact.
If the OS upgrade (or any other process) removes, say, python3.8, then no, venvs whose base interpreter is that python3.8 won't work anymore.
To demonstrate this in a Docker container, let's install Python 3.10 and 3.11, create venvs with both of them, then remove one base interpreter to see that the respective venv no longer works:
~ $ docker run -it ubuntu:22.04 bash
# apt update
[...snip...]
# apt install -y python3.10 python3.11 python3.10-venv python3.11-venv
[...snip...]
# python3.10 -m venv venv-310
# python3.11 -m venv venv-311
# venv-310/bin/python --version
Python 3.10.12
# venv-311/bin/python --version
Python 3.11.0rc1
# apt purge 'python3.10-*'
[...snip...]
# venv-310/bin/python --version
bash: venv-310/bin/python: No such file or directory
# venv-311/bin/python --version
Python 3.11.0rc1
# 


Thank you. This was very helpful. I knew about the copying of python files but was not sure of the base dependence. I am totally confused about why such a basic danger is not mentioned in many of the tutorials about the virtual environments.

Well, virtualenvs are meant to be disposable and you should strive for your virtualenvs to be recreatable at any time :)

Yes and no: when specifying --copies you can sometimes create properly self-contained environments. In fact, if I try exactly what you did but using --copies, the environment continues to work after removing the system installation of Python. However, this won’t reliably and depends on how Python was built. In a different scenario, the Python binary links to system libraries that are now missing.

@KonradRudolph, so using a dedicated base version using miniconda would be the way to go?

@xinit The way to go... to achieve what?

@xinit Depends on your use-case. I don’t use, and don’t recommend, Conda. In my experience it creates more issues than it solves. But I have complete control over my system installation (or rather: where I don’t have complete control and I need a self-contained installation I either use containers or I install my own Python).

As a note on that, Rye (an experimental tool for managing full Python toolchains) uses the indygreg/python-build-standalone standalone Python builds.

@KonradRudolph, sorry for vagueness in my query. I meant, creating venvs using miniconda based python. That way, venvs will have no dependency on system based python.

The way venvs work is that they bring along a whole Python runtime with them. Indeed if you activate the venv and then run which python you will not see your system Python, but the one installed by the venv.
In that way, if you upgrade your OS and that also upgrades your system Python, you won't have to worry because your venv will still have the old version vendored in place.

Thank you. And can I continue to add more virtual environments without worrying about underlying Python too?

This is not exactly true. Venvs do not bring the whole Python runtime with them; a venv depends on the base Python interpreter being intact.

@AKX ooh that's interesting to know, I had no idea. Does it just symlink to the system binary then?

virtual environment essentially copy from OS installation to the venv, so you will be maintainint all the libraries in the venv folder.
When you upgrade the OS the binaries will stay there and you will have both version available in different venv

This is not exactly true. Not everything is copied; the venv does depend on the base Python interpreter being intact.
